Streaming response from a POST request stops processing when in another browser tab
I am making an API call to OpenAI and getting a streaming response back. Here is the API call:
    response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { ...headers, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(request)
    });

The response.body property is thus a ReadableStream which is then processed via this snippet of code:
            var i = 1;
            for await (const event of readNDJSONStream(response.body)) {
                console.log("event", event);
                console.log(i);
                i++;
                if (event["context"] && event["context"]["data_points"]) {
                    event["message"] = event["delta"];
                    askResponse = event as ChatAppResponse;
                } else if (event["delta"]["content"]) {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    await updateState(event["delta"]["content"]);
                } else if (event["context"]) {
                    // Update context with new keys from latest event
                    askResponse.context = { ...askResponse.context, ...event["context"] };
                } else if (event["error"]) {
                    throw Error(event["error"]);
                }
            }

The streamed response is rendered in my webpage as it comes in, and so the user sees each word getting added to the page one at a a time as it gets streamed in.
The issue is that when I switch to another tab in the browser, the streaming and the rendering slows down tremendously (maybe only 1 line of text shows up in the webpage while spending around 5 minutes on a different tab), and then starts running quickly again once that I am back in the tab.
Is there something I can do to have it continue processing and rendering in the background while I am on another tab?

You might want to read some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77201871/insights-on-inactive-tab-throttling-involving-timers

Also search about web workers.
